# How to get updated jnlp file when using shortcuts?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

If my jnlp descriptor on the server changes and I start my application from the browser, a new jnlp file will be created in the cache and my desktop shortcuts will be updated to use the new jnlp file. (that's good so far).

But if I start my app using the desktop shortcut (or the menu entry), then my app won't know about the changed jnlp file on the server and will still use the cached outdated one.

Is it possible to force webstart not only to get the newest jarfiles but also update the jnlp file itsself when starting the app?

Background: I pass some parameters to my application (defined in the descriptor with the argument tag) to configure my app. If these arguments are changed - this must work of course too when using the shortcut.

I'm using java6 (u15).

EDIT: actually i've found this [java bug 6838214](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=b5fd9a3ad1e340ddfe9b1bbce00?bug_id=6838214) which seems to refer to my problem I think. If I interpret it correctly this should have been fixed in java6u14, but under u15 I still have this issue!

Comment: 6838214 fixes a bug reported in an earlier build of 6u14, so you should not have come across the bug on your own system.

Comment: ok I see. Maybe I haven't come across that particular bug - but the description fits to my case. Maybe it's just some configuration issue of the jnlp.

Comment: With short trying with Java 1.6.0_15 the JNLP file was refreshed from the server even in the case of desktop shortcuts. I'm not totally sure but maybe I got similar issues with 1.6.0_14 (didn't have time to uninstall _15 and reinstall and try with _14)

Comment: I have the same issue. In my case what changes frequently in the jnlp is the referenced jars inside `<resources>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you disallow offline-mode in the jnlp, it will always get the jnlp file from the server. I have tested this with the latest jre, not sure if it works with previous versions.